# Recursive query for heirarchal data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have data stored in a hierarchy. I need to have a query that can show me the hierarchy. So, a Bed is in a Cell, which is on a Floor, in a Building in a Block.

What I need to do is have a way to show a whole location, based on a given Location ID.

A person may be in a Bed, or in a Cell, or on a floor... or in a building. I have that location ID. What I need to do is display a description of where that person is.

For example, the person is in a Cell, which in the database, might be ID 350. I need to be able to build a string of his location, to show something like:

Cell 2, Floor 1, Building 1, Block 2

Or, the user is in Building 1 somewhere, so the ID for Building 1 might be 3. So I need to display Building 1, Block 2.

The two tables. One holds the locations, the other is just a lookup to see the types.

Is there an efficient way to query this sort of data? I may also have another requirement to display the where-abouts of hundreds of people, so the query is basically run a lot of times.

I tried a recursive CTE, but the examples I find only handle one level (I think?).

Maybe a function returning a Table would be the best way?
But the issue then is - depending on the 'Level' you start at, there may be less columns.

I need a way to handle this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location]
(
 [ID] Int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [ParentID] Int NULL,
 [LocationTypeID] Int NOT NULL,
 [Description] Varchar(100) NOT NULL
)
ON [PRIMARY]
go

-- Add keys for table dbo.Location

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Location] ADD CONSTRAINT [pk_location] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
 ON [PRIMARY]
go


CREATE TABLE [LocationType]
(
 [ID] Int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Description] Varchar(100) NOT NULL
)
ON [PRIMARY]
go

ALTER TABLE [LocationType] ADD CONSTRAINT [pk_location] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
 ON [PRIMARY]
go
```

Now we'll populate some lookup data:

```
INSERT INTO LocationType (Description) VALUES ('Bed')
INSERT INTO LocationType (Description) VALUES ('Cell')
INSERT INTO LocationType (Description) VALUES ('Floor')
INSERT INTO LocationType (Description) VALUES ('Building')
INSERT INTO LocationType (Description) VALUES ('Block')
```

And then create some location data.

```
-- Create the root items, which are the blocks. We'll have 2.

INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (NULL, 5, 'Block A') -- 1
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (NULL, 5, 'Block B') -- 2

-- Now add 3 buildings per block.

-- Block A
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (1, 4, 'Building 1') -- 3
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (1, 4, 'Building 2') -- 4
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (1, 4, 'Building 3') -- 5


-- Block B
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (2, 4, 'Building 1') -- 6
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (2, 4, 'Building 2') -- 7
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (2, 4, 'Building 3') -- 8

-- Now add two floors per building.

-- Building 1 Block A
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (3, 3, '1st Floor') -- 9
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (3, 3, '2nd Floor') -- 10

-- Building 2 Block A
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (4, 3, '1st Floor') -- 11
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (4, 3, '2nd Floor') -- 12

-- Building 3 Block A
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (5, 3, '1st Floor') -- 13
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (5, 3, '2nd Floor') -- 14




-- Building 1 Block B
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (6, 3, '1st Floor') -- 15
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (6, 3, '2nd Floor') -- 16

-- Building 2 Block B
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (7, 3, '1st Floor') -- 17
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (7, 3, '2nd Floor') -- 18

-- Building 3 Block B
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (8, 3, '1st Floor') -- 19
INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (8, 3, '2nd Floor') -- 20
```

-- Now, just a cursor to populate the cells and beds.

```
DECLARE @ThisID INT
DECLARE @Cntr INT  = 0

DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT id from Location where LocationTypeID = 3

OPEN mycursor

FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor
INTO @ThisID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @Cntr = 1
    WHILE(@Cntr < 20)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (@ThisID, 4, 'Cell ' + CAST(@Cntr AS VARCHAR))  
        SET @Cntr = @Cntr + 1
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor
    INTO @ThisID

END

CLOSE mycursor
DEALLOCATE mycursor


-- Now add two beds per cell
DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT id from Location where LocationTypeID = 4

OPEN my_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor
INTO @ThisID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (@ThisID, 5, 'Bed 1')   
    INSERT INTO Location (ParentId, LocationTypeID, Description) VALUES (@ThisID, 5, 'Bed 2')   

    FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor
    INTO @ThisID

END

CLOSE my_cursor
DEALLOCATE my_cursor
```

Comment: in Oracle you can just using connect by to solve this problem,but in sql server i'm not sure if there is a easy way to do this, i've heard about CTE but not familiar with that

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive CTE solution:

```
WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT
        l.*, CAST(l.Description AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS FullLoc
    FROM Location l
    INNER JOIN LocationType  lt ON lt.ID = l.LocationTypeID
    WHERE l.ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        l.*, CAST(l.Description AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ', ' + r.FullLoc
    FROM Location l
    INNER JOIN LocationType  lt ON lt.ID = l.LocationTypeID
    INNER JOIN rCTE r
        ON r.ID = l.ParentID
)
SELECT
    ID, FullLoc
FROM rCTE 
WHERE ID IN(21, 111, 190)
ORDER BY ID
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to solve this is by using LEFT JOIN..but it become tricky when hierarchy level is unknown or can become very deep.. if hierarchy level can be predetermined say 6 then this SQL code would work

```
SELECT
    L0.ID,
    L0.[Description] + 
    ISNULL(', ' + L1.[Description], '')  +
    ISNULL(', ' + L2.[Description], '')  +
    ISNULL(', ' + L3.[Description], '')  +
    ISNULL(', ' + L4.[Description], '')  +
    ISNULL(', ' + L5.[Description], '') FullLocation
FROM Location L0
    LEFT JOIN Location L1 ON L1.ID = L0.[ParentID]
    LEFT JOIN Location L2 ON L2.ID = L1.[ParentID]
    LEFT JOIN Location L3 ON L3.ID = L2.[ParentID]
    LEFT JOIN Location L4 ON L4.ID = L3.[ParentID]
    LEFT JOIN Location L5 ON L5.ID = L4.[ParentID]
WHERE
    L0.ID IN (21, 111, 190)
```

Result

```
╔═════╦═════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID  ║              FullLocation               ║
╠═════╬═════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  21 ║ Cell 1, 1st Floor, Building 1, Block A  ║
║ 111 ║ Cell 15, 1st Floor, Building 3, Block A ║
║ 190 ║ Cell 18, 1st Floor, Building 2, Block B ║
╚═════╩═════════════════════════════════════════╝
```